# Program can't find dll on my system when the dll is in system32

Tags: windows, dll, path

I have an application that I've written that requires cbw32.dll. On my computer, the dll is in c:\windows\system32, and c:\windows\system32 is on the path.

Here's the weirdness:

- This application has an installer, which I've used to install the application on my own computer.
- The installer does not distribute the dll.
- Our client, and their clients, install and run this software just fine.
- I installed the software on a co-worker's computer, and it worked just fine. Their only instance of the dll is in their c:\windows\system32.
- Our computers are both running Windows 7, 64-bit.

But it doesn't work on my computer.

Why would the software, which is distributed identically amongst all computers, not be able to find the dll on my computer, when the dll is exactly where it should be?

Comment: Is the DLL exactly the same version etc? Also, try putting it next to the executable (the programs exe) because it should also look there. Another thing, is your computer the same architecture (eg 64/32 bit) as all the others?

Comment: The DLLs were all the same version. Putting it next to the executable solved the issue, of course, but we needed to get to the root cause of the problem to figure out if we were going to have issues with distribution. Also, we'd like to not have to distribute the dll, so that if the dll is ever improved, we get that benefit in our software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahhhh... wtf. I read on another post on another forum that sysWOW64 is for 32-bit drivers, and that system32 is for 64-bit drivers. Copying the driver into sysWOW64 fixed the issue.

Not sure why everyone (except me) had a copy in both dll directories.

Comment: i.e. the infamous **sys**-"**WOW** this is a problem, where should we put 32-bit versions? oh I guess in the directory labeled **64**" screwup

Comment: Be aware I trashed a windows system by putting 64 bit dlls in WoW64. What drugs were they smoking when they named this folder?

Comment: Thank you, your solution saved me too. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out, regarding Mike's answer, that instead of copying the *.dll, you should probably instead download the appropriate Visual C++ Redistributable Package from the official Microsoft website (2010, 2013, etc...) which will install the right *.dll files on your system.

If you need them in sysWOW64, then download and install the x86 version of the package. Better yet, download and install both versions if you are on a 64-bit system. You can see which packages are installed in the Windows settings via "Apps & Features".